How do we advertise (announce) ideas discussed in meta to main site's users?
There was an idea: vote early, vote often. I like it and many users "here" do. But I don't think most of the registered users are aware of it. In my very early days here (before I registered), I didn't know the existence of meta site at all. Actually, I found meta by accident. 
I believe many users care about this site too, but they are not aware of the important issues this site faced and discussed here, such as "how to market this site" and "vote early and often". These things are easy favor for us, but they don't know this might be a big favor for this site. 
How do we advertise (announce) ideas discussed in meta to main site's users? especially good ideas?

My practice has been to post comments to relevant meta pages on appropriate questions or answers.  Moderators also have the ability to put occasional banners at the top of the site to advertise certain initiatives.  Overall, I believe the site has improved markedly since I posted some of my initial concerns regarding the site on meta, but I agree that there is not yet much of a "community" feel, mainly as the meta and particularly the chat are not very active.  If you feel strongly, as I do, about increasing the sense of community here, then start posting things to chat and we can brainstorm more ideas.

Well, there are several places we advertise meta, including the top navigation of every site, and the sidebar house ad area for questions with 2 or more answers.

Note that the sidebar ad won't appear for questions with 0 or 1 answers, and unless there are 4 or more answers, it will rotate through several possible house ads including ads for the network, ads for chat, the weekly newsletter, etcetera.
In general the governance on meta is an acquired taste, just like in real life. We certainly welcome participation here but we also recognize there are a huge number of users who just want expert questions and answers and aren't interested in governance.

? Mine screen doesn't have the "Visit Meta" advertisement? Why? Well, actually what I proposed is a little bit different. I was thinking to advertise the good ideas in meta for helping this site, "not advertise whole meta". Most of the discussion in meta will not interest users. They won't bother to spend time digging out the important ideas like voting and marketing, which is important to our current stage. In short, I think we need more direct and effective way to spread out the right things. It's good ideas worth spreading, not exactly whole meta.

Due to the characters limit, I didn't have space to thank for Jeff's kind answer. Thank you for addressing my question, Jeff!
